# How to avoid including full path to file

Tags: c#, file, path, streamreader

I've got a .csv-file that I've included in my project. I've created a StreamReader that takes a path as parameter, but I have to include the full path to the file instead of just the file name.

I.e. `new StreamReader("products.csv");` instead of

`new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Solution\Project\Products\products.csv");`

What can I do to make the StreamReader accept just a filename instead of a whole path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the file into your bin\debug folder and use this:

```
new StreamReader("products.csv");
```

Comment: @jmkjaer You're welcome. If you look at the properties for your project there is a section called Build Events, here you can add a macro to automatically copy files to your bin when you build the project.

Answer (score 2):

You can add root path to config

```
public class StreamReader
{
    private string _filePath;

    public StreamReader(string filePath)
    {
        _filePath = Path.IsPathRooted(filePath)
            ? filePath
            : Path.Combine(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CsvRootPath"], filePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll have to try that sometime and see what it does. For now though, I'll accept Clint's answer. Thank you though!